# How to add parts of lines from text files

Tags: python, file, text

What I am asked to do in this particular problem is to strip values from a text file(weather data), which I can do, and then add up digits 24-26 of each line (In weather data the digits 24-27 represent total precipitation for that day). Heres what I have so far.

```
inputFilename="weather.dat"
inputFile=open(inputFilename, "r")
for line in inputFile:
    line=line.strip()
    for item in line:
        q=0
        q=int(line[24:27])
        total=q+q
print("total precipitation: ",total)
```

I am by no means an expert. After running this I get an answer of 1120, when I should be getting an answer of 3164, and I really can't think of where to go from here.

Comment: post a snippet of your text file here

Comment: 035.5954-082.5568201001413059010000682.1

Comment: That is one line. There is about 8 more lines that are the same just with different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`line[24:27]` means **three** characters, the ones at indices 24, 25, and 26.  In Python, "right-side bound excluded" is the norm.

It's not very clear what you mean by "digits 24-27" (upper bound included or excluded?  IOW, is that three characters, or four?) but in case you meant "upper bound included", just change the slice to `line[24:28]`.

Comment: Another question is, if for *digits 24-27* OP starts counting with zero or 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're defining `total=q+q` inside your loop.  This is going to assign the value of each line (actually, double the value) to `total` over and over again, rather than maintain a running total.

Additionally, I'm not sure I understand why you're doing `for item in line`.  This is going to iterate over each of the characters in each line. If you know the precip is going to be at `line[24:27]` then you can just iterate over each line and add those amounts, rather than iterating over each line and then over each character.  It repeats work unnecessarily.